# Current day using \today for March give `Mars`

Tags: date

I'm using `\today` command to add current day to the document. For some reason it is printing `MARS` instead of `MARCH`.

[image]

I'm using this template
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-source-cv/wrdjtkkytqcw

Is this because months is shorted and how can I get the correct month working?

Comment: show a small, complete example, then we don't have to guess what you are doing.

Comment: 'mars' is March in French. Maybe you switched the language of your document accidentally.

Comment: Are you writing in French/Norwegian/Swedish?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Template included into the question

Comment: @Marijn Couldn't find a place where language is set

Comment: @RuixiZhang No, not at all.

Comment: The custom class loads babel with options english and french, thus the primary language is French. You might be able to switch it to English via `\selectlanguage{english} `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Overleaf template you're using is presented in French, that's why the date is written in French.

To change specifically the date in the footer, notice that the line 31 in the file `cv.tex` from the template is

```
        {\textsc{\today}} % \selectlanguage{english}\today
```

You can simple use the information in the comment and replace this line with

```
        {\selectlanguage{english}\textsc{\today}}
```

and the date in the footer will be in English rather than in French.

More generally, if you just don't want to write the CV in French, there is no need to load `babel` with the `french` option. In the file `yaac-another-awesome-cv.cls` from the template, `babel` is loaded with both `english` and `french` options at line 59, so you can just remove the `french` option. Doing this will also make the date appear in English.